# how to return a substring of 1000 numbers separately and then next 1000 numbers separately and so on from a string in java ?

Tags: java, substring, return-type

how to return a substring of 1000 numbers separately and then next 1000 numbers separately and so on from a string in java ? 
If the string length is 27500 then 27 substrings of 1000 numbers and 28th substring of 700 numbers in java using a return type function ?

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` and it's `subString` and `delete` methods

Answer (score 0):

Start by wrapping the `String` in a `StringBuilder`.

Use the `StringBuilder`'s `substring` method to get the next series and it's `delete` method to remove that series...

```
int length = Math.min(1000, stringBuilder.length());
String next = null;
if (length > 0) {
    next = stringBuilder.substring(0, length);
    // Remove the series from the StringBuilder
    stringBuilder.delete(0, length);
}
```

You could the wrap into a class which takes the master `String`, wraps it into a `StringBuilder` automatically and provides a simple `next` method, which will return `null` when no more series remain...

If you were really clever, you might even be able to wrap into some kind of `Iterator`